# Cascading ddl with jquery, asmx, but not MS ajax or plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

How can populate a ddl list dynamically (cascading ddl) using jquery w/o ms ajax framework or jquery plugins? (where I work am very limited on the libraries I can use).  I am using ASP.Net with jquery accessing an asmx webmethod.  The $.ajax call to the web method looks like the following:

```
function getText() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SearchFilters.asmx/HelloWorld",
        dataType: "html", // also tried "text"
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            $("#ddlCase").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

This return xml that looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">&lt;option value='1'&gt;Hello World&lt;/option&gt;</string>
```

In the success function, the js only clears out the values of the ddl:

```
$("#ddlCase").html(response)
```

Can this be done?  How can I decode the returned xml?  What am I missing?  Previously I attempted a datatype of json without success.  Please refer to the following:

[using JQuery .ajax, a Success method is not called when using jquery 'json' vs 'text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491549/using-jquery-ajax-a-success-method-is-not-called-when-using-jquery-json-vs-t)

Thanks! D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the source of my issue was the lack of the [ScriptService] attribute on the class decoration.  I changed to class declartion to:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class SearchFilters : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Using Fiddler I discovered the following error message was returned:

> Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class
>   definition can be called from script

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample Code which I worked few months ago.

ASP.NET HTML Code where you have two dropdowns a.) Category b.)Items

I have hardcoded the first DropDown with Categories: Fruits, Vegetables and Desserts. The Items DropDown is empty initially, since we will fill these through jQuery AJAX, when the onChange event of the Category DropDown will be fired.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Fruits</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Vegetables</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Desserts</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <br />
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#<%=ddlCategories.ClientID %>").change(
  function()
  {
   var category = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
   var ddlItems = document.getElementById("<%=ddlItems.ClientID%>");
   ddlItems.options.length = 0;
   $.ajax
   ({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url: "Webservice.asmx/getItems",
         data: "{'category':'"+category+"'}",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(msg)
         {
              var arrItems = msg.d.split("|");
              for(var i=0; i< arrItems.length; i++)
              {
                 var opt = document.createElement("option");
                 ddlItems.options.add(opt)
                 opt.text = arrItems[i];
                 opt.value = arrItems[i];
              }
         }
    });
  }
 );
 });
</script>


Webservice Code:


[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string getItems(string category)
{
  string strItems = "";
  if (category == "Fruits")
  {
    strItems = "Apple|Orange|Pinapple|Grapes";
  }
  else if (category == "Vegetables")
  {
    strItems = "Tomato|Cauliflower|Brinjal|Potato";
  }
  else if (category == "Desserts")
  {
    strItems = "Cakes|Cookies|IceCreams|Pastries";
  }
  return strItems;
}
```

Regards,

Sayed

(Please mark as answer if you find this article suitable)